# How to group by with aggregate operators?

Tags: python, pandas

Having trouble grouping by specific columns to then run aggregate operators on them. For example, need to group by week and region to calculate the total number of rejects/total number of deliveries at a rate if that makes sense?

Also, is there a way to filter Region in the group by as well?

```
DFrame.groupby('week_starting', 'Region').agg({"Rejects": "sum"} / {"deliveries": "sum"} )
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a syntax issue? Two columns need to be provided as a list ie. ['week_starting', 'Region' ] . Without seeing what DFrame is it's hard to say what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, filter to the region. Then, do the `groupby` with `sum` only, applying the sum to individual columns. Do the division between the two columns in the next step.

```
DFrame_sub = DFrame.loc[DFrame['Region'] == 'MyRegion']
g = DFrame_sub.groupby('week_starting', 'Region').agg({'Rejects': 'sum' , 'Deliveries' : 'sum'})
g['RejectRate'] = g['Rejects'] / g['Deliveries']
```